# Equivalent characterizations of rational normal curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

A rational normal curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}_k^d$ (assume $k= \mathbb{C}$) can be defined usually up to projective equivalence in two equivalent ways:

- smooth irreducible nondegenerate curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}^d$ of minimal degree $\text{deg}(C)=d$
- projectively equivalent to the image of the Veronese map

$$ \nu_d: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^d, \ \ \
[X_0:X_1] \mapsto [X_0^d: X_0^{d-1}X_1:..., X_1^d]  $$

The second definition can be reprased as that there exist a $\mathbb{C}$-basis of the vector space of homogeneous polynomials $p_0,p_1,..., p_d$ of degree $d$ in two variables $X_0, X_1$ such that $C$ is the image under

$$ P: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^d, \ \ \
[X_0:X_1] \mapsto [p_0(X): p_1(X):..., p_d(X)]  $$

In Harris' book *[Algebraic Geometry](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9780387977164)*, on page 14 there is an alternative presumably equivalent construction of a rational normal curve:
Start by choosing $d$ codimension two linear
spaces $\Lambda_i \cong \mathbb{P}^{d-2} \subset \mathbb{P}^{d}$. The family $\{H_i(\lambda)\}$ of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{P}^{d}$ containing $\Lambda_i$ is
then parameterized by $\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^1$; choose such parameterizations, subject to the condition
that for each $\lambda$ the planes $H_1(\lambda), ... , H_d(\lambda)$ are independent, i.e., intersect in a
point $ p(\lambda)$. Claim: It is then the case that the locus of these points $p(\lambda)$ as $\lambda$ varies in $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a rational normal curve.

*Question:* Why this construction gives a rational normal curve $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_1(\lambda) \cap ... \cap H_d(\lambda)$?

I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170453/steiner-construction-of-rational-normal-curve) a rather promising approach discussing identical problem: in the linked discussion is showed how one can construct explicitly the point $p(\lambda)= [p_0(\lambda): p_1(\lambda):...: p_d(\lambda)]$ in terms of certain homogenous polynomials $p_i(\lambda)$ of degree $d$ in coordinates $(\lambda)=\lambda_0, \lambda_1$.

The idea is quite simple. Consider the $(d+1) \times (d+1)$ matrix $A(\lambda)$ where each $j$-th row of $A(\lambda)$ is encoded by the $j$-th family of hyperplanes as follows. The parametrized family $H_j(\lambda)$ of hyperplanes which contain $\Lambda_i \cong \mathbb{P}^{d-2}$ is given as vanishing loci of $\lambda_0S_j +\lambda_1T_j$, where
the two linear forms $S_j, T_j$ in  variables $Y_0,..., Y_d$ determine $\Lambda_j$. The $j$-th row of $A(\lambda)$ is encoded in

$$a_0(\lambda)Y_0+ a_1(\lambda)Y_1 +...+ a_d(\lambda)Y_d=  \lambda_0S_j +\lambda_1T_j   $$

The $(d+1)$-row is filled with zeroes. The adjugate matrix $P(\lambda)$ having $d$-minors of $A$ as entries satisfies $A \cdot P=P \cdot A= \text{det}(A) \cdot E_{d+1} $ and $\text{det}(A) $ is zero. The $(d+1)$-th column of $P(\lambda)$ is the unique point $p(\lambda)=[p_0(\lambda): p_1(\lambda):...: p_d(\lambda)]$ with homogeneous $p_i(\lambda)$ of degree $d$.

One expects finally to obtain the rational normal curve as image  of

$$[X_0:X_1] \mapsto [p_0(X): p_1(X):..., p_d(X)]  $$

but it isn't clear why the $p_i(\lambda)$ are linearly *independent*. If they aren't, we obtain a degenerate curve in the image, that's not what we want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{P}^d = \mathbb{P}(V)$. A hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}(V)$ corresponds to an epimorphism $V \to k$, a pencil of hyperplanes to an epimorphism
$$
V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1),
$$
and a collection of $d$ pencils to a morphism
$$
f \colon V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)^{\oplus d}.
$$
The condition imposed on the pencils means that this is an epimorphism, therefore its kernel $\mathrm{Ker}(f)$ is a line subbundle in $V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$, and computing its determinant it is easy to see that
$$
\mathrm{Ker}(f) \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-d).
$$
The embedding $\mathrm{Ker}(f) \to V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ induces a degree $d$ map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}(V)$, and its image is precisely the curve in question. By this construction, it is a rational normal curve of degree $d$.

EDIT. To show that the curve is nondegenerate, consider the exact sequence
$$
0 \to 
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-d) \to 
V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \stackrel{f}\to
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)^{\oplus d} \to 
0
$$
obtained above. Dualizing it, we obtain
$$
0 \to 
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)^{\oplus d} 
\stackrel{f^\vee}\to
V^\vee \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \to
\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(d) \to 
0.
$$
Since the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-1)$ has no cohomology, the induced morphism
$$
V^\vee = 
H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, 
V^\vee \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}) \to
H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(d))
$$
is an isomorphism. This means that the curve is nondegenerate.

Comment: I understand that this construction gives this degree $d$ map $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}(V)$, and so the image is a degree $d$ curve, but why is this curve *nondegenerate*? Does it somehow follow immediately from the construction?

Comment: I updated the answer to include an explanation of nondegeneracy.

Comment: So the cohomology assures that for the resulting map
$\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}(V)$ - which in general
- up to projective equivalence - defined by 
any set of $d+1$ generators of the image of the last
map $V^\vee  \to
H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(d))$, right? This cohomological argument I understand now, but the geometric 
picture behind it stays nebulous. The map $f$ in your answer 
corresponds to the modern/sheaf theoretic incarnation of the
matrix $A(\Lambda)$ I defined above, 
matrix with entries in
the space of homogeneous

Comment: linear forms 
$W:= \mathbb{C}\lambda_0 +\mathbb{C}\lambda_1$ in $\lambda_0, \lambda_1$. 

I think that it is also possible with more "elementary tools"
to see that the image in nondegenerate. If we set 
$U:= \mathbb{C}^d$, then every column of $A(\Lambda)$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-
vector of $W \otimes U$. The claim is that from the condition 
on the pencils it follows that the $d+1$ columns vectors are linearly 
independent in $W \otimes U$. The elementary column operations on 
$A(\lambda)$ correspond to changing the coordinates $Y_0,..., Y_d$ realized by

Comment: multiplication of $A$ by $GL_{d+1}$ from the
right - so these not change the projective equivalence 
class of the resulting morphism $\mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^d$,
especially not the rank $d$ of $A(\lambda)$.

Comment: If the columns would be linearly independent, then after 
appropriate base change we would obtain a matrix
$A'(\lambda)$ having zero vector as $(d+1)$-column. This would imply
by construction that the resulting curve is the point $[0:...: 1]$,
contradiction, therefore all $d+1$ columns are linear 
independent in $W \otimes U$. Then the $d$-minors of 
$A(\lambda)$ must be linearly independent too, since pairwise distict
tuples of basis elements give linear independent elements
in exterior sum. Hope, that the argument should work.

Comment: A nitpick: do you maybe see if it is also possible to deduce 
that the curve $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \mathbb{P}^{1}} H_1(\lambda) \cap ... \cap H_d(\lambda)$
cannot be contained in a hyperplane from pure elementary geometric 
considerations "synthetic geomtry") on the given famifies of planes? I'm wondering if after 
having a cohomological proof, a a linear algebra proof 
(if my proof above works) it also possible to give a  
proof with pure methods from synthetic geometry.

Comment: Sure, an argument not using sheaves and cohomology is possible, but it is too large to fit in the comment field.

Comment: I intend to open a discussion in MSE about the ways to solve the same 
problem using "elmentary" geometric methods in the coming days.
I would be very grateful if you could maybe sketch the idea
there. Even though I learned now that the statement is true,
I have actually a rather bad geometric intuition why 
that should hold. So I hoped that maybe a geometrical proof may provide a better geometric insight.

Comment: No problem, see an explanation I wrote there.